# See All Status Bar Text in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a problem with the SublimeText 3 status bar having too much information from my packages. The problem is that the text gets cutoff. Is there a command or a way to see all of the text in the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

Few different options in my opinion as follows, sorry if its not specific but I don't know exactly how you have your screen resolution, sublime text setup and its packages therein.

1. Without being able to easily duplicate this problem myself I would advise trying to change the screen resolution and see if that is the issue and go from there.
2. You can try to write your own theme to determine the status bar size
   e.g.:

   https://gist.github.com/zbyna/5250fd49a805fd0fe0853cb5256101ee
3. You can try and find something different in terms of a status bar or what allows you to customise it at: https://packagecontrol.io/ although I could not find one here or anywhere else the size of the status bar mostly seems to be done at the theme level.
4. Try and configure the packages to show less text? Which packages do you currently have installed?